# Angular 1 : Component, State, Route or Directive?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, components, state, directive

Some of my personal remarks :

- Component can be loaded dynamically through an URL.
  For example : An article can be coded in Component and can be reached at journal.com/articles/43
- Directive does the same job but does not own a specific URL.
  But after all of that, I get lost because State and Route have the same functionalities.

So, for every Angular developer, we all have in our mind the same question : In which circumstance, which architecture and how, can we use efficiently a Component, a State, a Route or a Directive ? Because they all have a View and a Controller.

Answer (score 1):

A **component** is the newest of all the things, and is a simplification of directives. You should use them, as they are becoming the new standard of Angular 2 and React.

A component is not owned by URL by default. You are talking about the **angular-ui-router** library, but the relation is on the other way, one url is tied to a component. A component can appears in multiple url.

A **state**, always in the context of the angular-ui-router, is kind of the same thing as an url, or a **route**. It's just different names for basically the same thing.

Finally, a **directive** is the kind of old stuff of angular, which is still useful if you need direct manipulation of the DOM, but that is an advanced use case.

Conclusion: you have **components**, which are reacheable throught differents **states**. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I've checked Directive and I see that : Directive can handle DOM manipulation through the LINK function and TRANSCLUDE property